# Using ANTLR parser in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4, codemirror

I'm trying to integrate my ANTLR4 parser into CodeMirror text editor. When I add the following line to my html file:

```
var antlr4 = require('antlr4/index'); // index is an ANTLR runtime file
```

I'm getting following errors in Chrome:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///home/enes/Desktop/git/text_editor_mirror/antlr4/index.js'.
at require (file:///home/enes/Desktop/git/text_editor_mirror/lib/require.js:179:10)
at file:///home/enes/Desktop/git/text_editor_mirror/index.html:411:16

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/enes/Desktop/git/text_editor_mirror/antlr4/index.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

So, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the browser is trying to fetch it from the local filesystem (`file:///` will cause error). You need to serve js files(antlr runtime files and generated js files also) from a server(`http://`). `Python-Flask` can be used to easily host js files over a server.

Follow the link to serve files using `Flask`
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_from_directory

Browsers don't allow scripts loaded from local file system to run along secured websites. So in order to avoid that you need to call scripts from a server. If local server doesn't help, you can push these scripts to Github and call them using CDN service like Gitraw .